# Anaconda Navigator 2019.03 not opening in Windows 10

Tags: anaconda

Anaconda Navigator 2019.03 not opening in Windows 10. Two blank screens open and close. The Navigator does not start.

When in Anaconda command prompt I get the error

Could Not Find C:\Users\Anand Jayakumar A\AppData\Local\Temp\conda-7568.tmp

Error Message
(base) C:\Users\Administrator>conda update
WARNING: The conda.compat module is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.

CondaValueError: no package names supplied

## If you want to update to a newer version of Anaconda, type:

#

## $ conda update --prefix C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3 anaconda

(base) C:\Users\Administrator>conda update --prefix C:\ProgramDats\Anaconda3 anaconda
WARNING: The conda.compat module is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.

## >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1003, in __call__
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 84, in _main
    exit_code = do_call(args, p)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\conda_argparse.py", line 82, in do_call
    exit_code = getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_update.py", line 20, in execute
    install(args, parser, 'update')
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\install.py", line 166, in install
    if args.mkdir:
AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'mkdir'
```

`$ C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py update --prefix C:\ProgramDats\Anaconda3 anaconda`

environment variables:
                 CIO_TEST=
                CLASSPATH=C:\xpressmp\lib\xprm.jar;C:\xpressmp\lib\xprs.jar;C:\xpressmp\lib\xprb
                          .jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\LINGO\Lingo12.jar
        CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV=base
                CONDA_EXE=C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\condabin..\Scripts\conda.exe
               CONDA_EXES="C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\condabin..\Scripts\conda.exe"
             CONDA_PREFIX=C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
    CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER=(base)
               CONDA_ROOT=C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
              CONDA_SHLVL=1
                 HOMEPATH=\Users\Administrator
                     PATH=C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\condabin..;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\condabin
                          ..\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\condabin..\Library
                          \usr\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\condabin..\Library\bin;C:\ProgramDa
                          ta\Anaconda3\condabin..\Scripts;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\condabin..\
                          bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w6
                          4\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda
                          3\Library\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda
                          3\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\condabin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3;C:\Pr
                          ogramData\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib
                          rary\usr\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaco
                          nda3\Scripts;C:\Program Files\IBM\SPSS\ModelerSubscription\1.0\ext\bin
                          \spss.TMWBServer\bin;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a\bin;C:\Program
                          Files\MATLAB\R2018a\bin\win64;C:\SIMULIA\Commands;C:\Program
                          Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\;C:\Program
                          Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community128\opl\bin\x64_win64;C:\Program
                          Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community128\opl\oplide\;C:\Program Files\
                          IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community128\cplex\bin\x64_win64;C:\Program File
                          s\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community128\cpoptimizer\bin\x64_win64;C:\Prog
                          ram Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\xpressmp\bin;C:\x
                          pressmp\workbench;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA
                          Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Rockwell Software\RSCommon;C
                          :\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\GAMS\win64\25.1;C:\GAMS\win64\25
                          .1\gbin;C:\Program Files\PTC\MKS Toolkit\bin64;C:\Program
                          Files\PTC\MKS Toolkit\bin;C:\Program Files\PTC\MKS
                          Toolkit\bin\X11;C:\Program Files\PTC\MKS Toolkit\mksnt;C:\Program
                          Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\
                          Windows\System32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\wbem;C:\Windows\System
                          32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R)
                          Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R)
                          Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R)
                          Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R)
                          Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
                          Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
                          Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client
                          SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\LINGO\;C:\Program
                          Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
                          Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a\runtime\win64;C:
                          \WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\Syste
                          m32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program
                          Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common
                          Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
                          Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\GAMS\win64\24.7;C:\GAMS\win64\
                          24.7\gbin;C:\Pro;C:\Users\Anand Jayakumar
                          A\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files (x86)\Wolfram
                          Research\WolframScript\;C:\Program Files (x86)\National
                          Instruments\Shared\LabVIEW CLI;C:\Program Files\Geometric\DFMPro for
                          SolidWorks(x64)\DFMPro\;C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\;C:
                          \texlive\2018\bin\win32;C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft
                          \WindowsApps;
             PSMODULEPATH=C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\Windows
                          PowerShell\v1.0\Modules
       REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=
            SSL_CERT_FILE=

```
 active environment : base
active env location : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
        shell level : 1
   user config file : C:\Users\Administrator\.condarc
```

populated config files :
          conda version : 4.6.11
    conda-build version : 3.17.8
         python version : 3.7.3.final.0
       base environment : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\Administrator.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\Administrator.conda\envs
                          C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.6.11 requests/2.21.0 CPython/3.7.3 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.17134
          administrator : True
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False

An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.

If submitted, this report will be used by core maintainers to improve
future releases of conda.
Would you like conda to send this report to the core maintainers?

Upload did not complete.

Thank you for helping to improve conda.
Opt-in to always sending reports (and not see this message again)
by running

```
$ conda config --set report_errors true
```

(base) C:\Users\Administrator>conda update

Comment: This [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46335789/anaconda-navigator-wont-launch-windows-10) may be of some assistance.

Comment: Unable to change user name

Comment: Changed to C:\Anaconda but still not working